# uncaught error NOT_FOUND_ERR DOM Exception 8

Tags: javascript, exception, appendchild

So I am deleting all the contents under a particular div and adding a message content. However, javascript throw the following error after the finish:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Here is the code where it is executed

```
 new Ajax.Request("profileThis.php",
 {
   method:'post',

   parameters:{title:title, review:review, userId:userId, category:category, categoryId:categoryId},

   onSuccess:function(ajax) 
   {
    alert(ajax.responseText); // this is just for debugging purposes

    var message=ajax.responseText;

    var divMessage=document.createElement("div");

    divMessage.style.color="rgb:(105,105,105)";

    divMessage.innerHTML=message;

    while($("reviewSheet").hasChildNodes)
    {
     $("reviewSheet").removeChild($("reviewSheet").lastChild);
    }

    $("reviewSheet").adopt(divMessage);         

   },

   onFailure:ajaxFailure,

   onException:ajaxFailure

 });
```

People commented that the problem was with how I assigned `divMessage` to `reviewSheet`. I tried both `adopt` and `appendChild` but none works. 
 A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: _$("reviewSheet")_ What it's? You uses javascript frameworks, or it an alias for `document.getElementById()`? If you need to remove all nodes from element (empty element) simply use `element.innerHTML='';`

Comment: Or instead of `element.innerHTML=''` use code: `while(someParentElement.firstChild)someParentElement.removeChild(someParentElement.firstChild);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
divMessage.style.color="rgb:(105,105,105)";
```

should be

```
divMessage.style.color="rgb(105,105,105)";
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. I tried but its still displaying the same. I don't think its a CSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you are calling the method hasChildNodes() on a jQuery object? I'm not sure what $("reviewSheet") is supposed to be, but wrapping a string in $() makes it a jQuery object which I don't believe will work with regular javascript methods. If "reviewSheet" is the id of an element you could do something like

```
node = document.getElementById('reviewSheet');
```

then you could go into your while loop.

```
while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
 //the rest of your code here
}
```

Oh also you need to put the parenthesis after hasChildNodes() to return a boolean value.